# "None of the configured nodes are available" - A Run Time Erro on Cloud Foundry

Tags: jhipster, cloud-foundry

A JHipster generated app is running fine on my local box. It doesn't run properly on CF. Here are some related log messages.

```
2017-07-18T15:54:52.925-07:00 [RTR/4] [OUT] abc.cfapps.io - [2017-07-18T22:54:52.660+0000] "POST /api/suppliers?cacheBuster=1500418492191 HTTP/1.1" 500 1973 103 "https://abc.cfapps.io/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/58.0.3029.110 Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36" "10.10.66.225:14527" "10.10.149.25:61049" x_forwarded_for:"24.22.244.84" x_forwarded_proto:"https" vcap_request_id:"0957d097-572b-4531-623b-16644a0539ba" response_time:0.264529771 app_id:"94a37d49-422b-4354-b381-ebdd8e4b6cb8" app_index:"0" x_b3_traceid:"61424f4f1657ba89" x_b3_spanid:"61424f4f1657ba89" x_b3_parentspanid:"-"
2017-07-18T15:54:52.926-07:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2017-07-18 
22:54:52.925 ERROR 21 --- [ XNIO-2 task-9] c.m.m.w.rest.errors.ExceptionTranslator : An unexpected error occurred: None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{localhost}{127.0.0.1:9300}]
2017-07-18T15:55:04.945-07:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2017-07-18 22:55:04.945 ERROR 21 --- [ XNIO-2 task-10] c.m.m.w.rest.errors.ExceptionTranslator : An unexpected error occurred: None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{localhost}{127.0.0.1:9300}]
2017-07-18T15:55:20.440-07:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2017-07-18 22:55:20.440 ERROR 21 --- [ XNIO-2 task-11] c.m.m.w.rest.errors.ExceptionTranslator : An unexpected error occurred: None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{localhost}{127.0.0.1:9300}]
```

What I can do to fix this "None of the configured nodes are available" problem?

Update:

It seems to be a ElasticSearch problem, something to do with its configuration in JHipster.

Comment: I don't know the CF sub generator but the usual error with elasticsearch jhipster apps in prod profile is that user forgot to instantiate an elasticsearch instance (see https://jhipster.github.io/using-elasticsearch/). So someone has to provision an elasticsearch cluster, either it's you through dashboard or it's the CF sub generator but I can't see it in its code

Comment: @GaëlMarziou Thanks for your inputs. I selected dev for the CF deployment. The other option is prod. The app is setup a H2Memory for the dev environment. During the deployment setup process, I am asked for PostgreSQL configuration on CF. I guess the app DB configuration is override and H2 won't run on CF. Back to ElasticSearch, I can't see anything about ElasticSearch on my CF dashboard.

Comment: Maybe you should ask CF support

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: No. I use something else instead of CF.