# JHipster - Heroku - None of the configured nodes are available

Tags: heroku, jhipster

I'm just playing around deploying a monolithic JHipster application to Heroku.

I followed [these](https://jhipster.github.io/heroku/) instructions. It seems to deploy ok ~ tables are created and the static data is loaded. I can login and navigate the site.

However, when I try to update or create anything I get an internal server error. After running `heroku log` as per [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging), I see the following error:

> ERROR 4 --- [ XNIO-2 task-32] o.h.m.w.rest.errors.ExceptionTranslator  : An unexpected error occurred: None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{localhost}{127.0.0.1:9300}]
>   2017-08-09T22:25:52.182502+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=DELETE

When running the app locally, mvn (dev profile) and H2 database everything works fine. Can anyone give me a pointer of how to proceed?

JHipster v4.6.2 / Angular 4 / PostgreSQL

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, when I generated my app I selected elastic search. As per [here](http://jhipster.github.io/using-elasticsearch):

> JHipster expects an external Elasticsearch instance

... and as mentioned by Gael in the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45178630/none-of-the-configured-nodes-are-available-a-run-time-erro-on-cloud-foundry):

> the usual error with elasticsearch jhipster apps in prod profile is that user forgot to instantiate an elasticsearch instance

... and indeed, in my `application-prod.yml`, I had this:

```
    data:
    elasticsearch:
        cluster-name:
        cluster-nodes: localhost:9300
```

For the time being, I have just commented this out and redeployed the app to Heroku as per [here](https://jhipster.github.io/heroku/).

Thanks,